# How to scroll to top every time Page is displayed

Tags: sapui5

In my UI5 application, if I scroll to bottom of one page and then move to another page, and then again come back to the previous page, the view is at the bottom of the page. That is, the last scroll position of that page is preserved and I have to scroll up again to see the top part. I want to display the page from top every time I visit it.

Any suggestions?

```xml
<Page id="page" showHeader="false">
  <VBox height="2000px">
    <core:Fragment fragmentName="ABC" type="XML" />
    <core:Fragment fragmentName="PQR" type="XML" />
  </VBox>
</Page>
```

```js
return BaseController.extend("....somePage", {
  onInit: function() {
    // .....
  },
  _onObjectMatched: function(oEvent) {
    this.getView().byId("page").scrollTo(0); // even this is not working
    window.scrollTo(0,0); // did not work
  },
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `scrollTo` or `scrollToElement` methods of [sap.m.Page](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Page/methods/Summary)? If you do, make sure to set the `enableScrolling` property to true. I've added a small example below.

**View**

```xml
<Page id="page" title="ScrollPage" enableScrolling="true">
  <!-- your content-->
</Page>
```

**Controller**

This will trigger the scroll function everytime you visit the page.

```js
onInit: function() {
  const route = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().getRoute("thisPage");
  route.attachPatternMatched(this.onPagePatternMatched, this);
},

onPagePatternMatched: function() {
  this.byId("page").scrollTo(0);
},
```